# UIImageView image not returning nil but image not showing

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, nsurl, nlog, null

I have an image view and it pulls url from the internet this is the url that I got from the RSS Feed -
 its an image pulled from rss feed `.xml` here is code I use to get image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.something.com/rss/hi.xml"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    // Assuming data is in UTF8.
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];




    NSString *webStringz = string;




    NSString *mastaString;

    mastaString = webStringz;



    NSScanner *theScanner2;
    NSString *imageURL2;

    theScanner2 = [NSScanner scannerWithString: mastaString];

    // find start of tag
    [theScanner2 scanUpToString: @"<media:content url=\"" intoString: nil];
    if ([theScanner2 isAtEnd] == NO) {

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner2 scanUpToString: @"\" " intoString: &imageURL2];
        imageURL2 = [imageURL2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<media:content url=\"" withString:@""];

        imageURL2 = [imageURL2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        imageURL2 = [imageURL2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                //Download Image
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageURL2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]])];

        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        [imageView setImage:image];

        NSLog(@"Image URL #1: %@", imageURL2);
        mastaString = [mastaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:imageURL2 withString:@""];

        if (imageView.image == nil) {
            NSLog(@"IS NIL");

        }
        else if (image == nil) {
            NSLog(@"IS NIL");

        }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

}
```

In my NSLOG it says the image url and its valid.
It DOES NOT show the IS NIL
It DOES NOT show the IS NIL 2

But the ImageView is not showing the image? Why? Its all linked up and everything?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the imageView to the view hierarchy ?

Comment: I don't know what that means sorry Im very new.

Comment: Well, if you didn't add the image view to the root view (in most cases it is the view of your view controller ), you can't see it though it is allocated.

Comment: Yeh then I did add it to the view hierarchy

Comment: Im going to make a completely new project and try the same code on that project see if it works

Comment: Ok this is weird when I copy pasted code into other project the image showed up.

Comment: It must be that you didn't create the image view when the first time that you access the view of UIViewController. Note that self.view will trigger `viewDidLoad` method if it is nil, then the imageView is nil. So you'b better create the imageView in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: ok your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be that you didn't create the image view when the first time you access the view of UIViewController. Note that self.view will trigger viewDidLoad method if it is nil, but then the imageView is nil. So you'b better create the imageView in viewDidLoad method.